# create a new column in pandas DataFrame based on two others which contain NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

I have a pandas `DataFrame` `df`

```
                  L C
0         [1, 2, 3] 5
1       [4, nan, 6] 0
2   [nan, nan, nan] 15
```

and another `DataFrame` `other`

```
    C
0   0
1   25
2   0
```

Then I append `other` to `df` and in L column are added 3 rows with NaN values.

```
                  L C   
0         [1, 2, 3] 5   
1       [4, nan, 6] 0   
2   [nan, nan, nan] 15  
0               NaN 0   
1               NaN 25  
2               NaN 0
```

I want to create a column that if `L` column is `NaN` and `C` is `0` then it will get value `1` otherwise it will get value `0`. I also make computations with rows that do not contain `NaN` values but it is out of the purpose of this post.

I found that the way Pandas deals with `Nan` values is `pd.isna()`.

I created the function

```
def check_cols(L, C):
  if pd.isna(L) and C == 0:
    return 1
  elif pd.isna(L) and C != 0:
    return 0
```

and I apply the function on every row

```
df['col'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_cols(row.L,row.C), axis=1)
```

but i get the error

**The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

because it checks every element of the list if is `NaN`. I don't want to check the elements of the list if there are `NaN` or not, i want want to check if there is a list (even with all elements nan) or a `NaN` value. Another way to do it is to create a column with `pd.isna()` like this

```
                  L C   is_NaN
0         [1, 2, 3] 5   False
1       [4, nan, 6] 0   False
2   [nan, nan, nan] 15  False
0            NaN    0   True
1            NaN    25  True
2            NaN    0   True
```

and then give three columns as an argument to the function, which will work. I want to do the same check, if there is a list and if there is a `NaN` value, within the function without having to create extra column.

If someone would explain why in the first case it checks every element of the list and in the second it does the check that I want, and/or provide some sources, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the exception is that you should use `&` instead of `and` and also the `if condition` cannot evaluate to either `True` or `False` because the output is a `Series` of Booleans. Example:

```
pd.isna(df.L) & df.C == 0

0     True
1     True
2     True
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

The result above cannot be evaluated by an `if condition`.

Here's a solution that returns directly the condition you mentioned:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def check_cols(L, C):
    return pd.isna(df.L) & (df.C == 0)

data = {
    'L': [[1, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'C': [5, 0, 15, 0, 25, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=[0, 1, 2, 0, 1 ,2])

res = check_cols(df.L, df.C)
df['res'] = res
df
```

**# EDIT: Updated solution according to comments**

Then the issue is that you are applying `pd.isna` to a list - for example in the first row `L = [1, 2, 3]` in the first row and that cannot be evaluated by the `if condition`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def check_cols(L, C):
    if not isinstance(L, list) and np.isnan(L) and C == 0:
        return 1
    elif not isinstance(L, list) and np.isnan(L) and C != 0:
        return 0 
    else:
        # when L is a list
        return 1

data = {
    'L': [[1, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'C': [5, 0, 15, 0, 25, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=[0, 1, 2, 0, 1 ,2])

df['col'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_cols(row.L,row.C), axis=1)
df
```

EDIT 2: I decided to go for `np.nan` but it also works with `pd.na`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, I did not write it completely right. `check_cols` function is used with apply(). I will edit my post. The reason I use apply is because as I mentioned if the value is not `NaN` I also do other computations, I am not interested just if the value is `NaN` or not.

Comment: I updated the answer to the added requirements. The problem is still identical in the if condition we need to have a single value that can be evaluated to True or False and when it runs with a list it will return `[False, False, True]` for example.

Comment: Basically what I want is to do within the function the same check `df.L.isna()` does inside the method, in other words the `isNaN` column. This check does not bother how many elements does the list have and what values, it just checks if there is a list or a NaN values, if I understand it correctly. Is this possible?